# convert letter from a list into a number depending on another list in python

Tags: python, list, encryption

I want to convert each letter of the list word to a number depending on the lists character and number. So a = 0, b = 02300, c = 2.
I want this output:

```
encoding = [34, 9, 432, 432, 104, 124546324, 104693, 104, 432, 5]
```

ps: It's not import if there's no space between each number.

```
word = ["Hello world"]
    encoding = []
    charachter = ["a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m","n","o","p","q","r","s","t","u","v","w","x","y","z",""]
    number = [0,02300,2,5,9,7,10,34,876,23,125,432,567,103,104,10234,102435,332,7654,12435,65434,12121,104693,130694,120357,12346,124546324]
```

I don't no what to do because the numbers of the list number are not equal to the index of the letters in the list character.

PS: I hope there's not another topic like this because I didn't find it

Comment: 02300 is not a valid integer. Would strings in `number` be ok?

Comment: First of all, you'll need a map `character -> number`: `Map = dict(zip(character, number))`...

Comment: Also how is the `""` -> `124546324` mapping supposed to work? There's a lot of empty strings in any string...

Comment: THere is no mapping for capital `H` - there is no mapping for space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a dictionary using [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/functions.html#zip) and [`map`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/functions.html#map) to match the corresponding letter with the encryption number.

```
word = "Hello world"
encoding = []
charachter = ["a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m","n","o","p","q","r","s","t","u","v","w","x","y","z",""]
number = [0,2300,2,5,9,7,10,34,876,23,125,432,567,103,104,10234,102435,332,7654,12435,65434,12121,104693,130694,120357,12346,124546324]

lookup = dict(zip(charachter,number))
output = " ".join(list(map(lambda elem: str(lookup.get(elem,' ')), word.lower())))
print(output)
```

Output:

```
34 9 432 432 104   104693 104 332 432 5
```

Answer (score 2):

Your post contains quite a few irregularities, such as missing characters, illegal integers, missing mappings and that peculiar translation for the empty string - so I'm going to answer in general.

What you want (what I gathered from "It's not import if there's no space between each number") is a translation table that maps characters to their translation. You can get it by passing a mapping of characters to strings to `str.maketrans`.

```
>>> char_to_number = {'a': '0', 'b': '02300', 'c': '2'} # ... and so on
>>> translator = str.maketrans(char_to_number)
>>> plain = 'abcabc'
>>> 
>>> plain.translate(translator)
'00230020023002'
```

If you actually do want a list, use

```
>>> [char_to_number[c] for c in plain]
['0', '02300', '2', '0', '02300', '2']
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [zip()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) to create a lookup dictionary.

```
word = "Hello world"
encoding = []
charachter = ["a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m","n","o","p","q","r",
              "s","t","u","v","w","x","y","z",""]
number = [0,2300,2,5,9,7,10,34,876,23,125,432,567,103,104,10234,102435,332,7654,12435,
          65434,12121,104693,130694,120357,12346,124546324]

mapping = {k:v for k,v in zip(charachter,number)}  # or dict(zip(...))

enc = [mapping.get(c, c) for c in word.lower()] # use character as default if not mapped

print(enc)  # [34, 9, 432, 432, 104, ' ', 104693, 104, 332, 432, 5]
```

I opted to lowercase your input (and moved it to a normal string, not a list of strings with one string in it).

If a character is not mapped, it will use it instead of a number (f.e. for the space).

You can create a space seperated string fom it with:

```
s = ' '.join(map(str,enc))
print( s )
```

Output:

```
34 9 432 432 104   104693 104 332 432 5
```

See [Why dict.get(key) instead of dict[key]?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11041405/why-dict-getkey-instead-of-dictkey) for `dict.get()`

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

```
word = "Hello world"
encoding = []
character = ["a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m","n","o","p","q","r","s","t","u","v","w","x","y","z"," "]
number = [0,02300,2,5,9,7,10,34,876,23,125,432,567,103,104,10234,102435,332,7654,12435,65434,12121,104693,130694,120357,12346,124546324]

# create a dictionary with keys as characters and values as numbers
mapping = {}
for i in range(0,27):
    mapping[character[i]] = number[i]

# now iterate over the string and look up the dictionary for each character
for x in word:
    encoding.append(mapping[x.lower()])

print(encoding)
```

Note:

1. I'm treating `word` as a string(`word = "Hello world"`) rather than an array of strings(`word = ["Hello world"]`).
2. I've replaced the last item (`""`) in the character array with a space (`" "`). We need this to replace the space between `Hello` and `world`.